# How can I signal that I don't intend to follow up the items in my "Future Work" section?

Tags: publications, computer-science

I'm currently writing a paper that is based on work that I won't be following up on, as I'm changing career directions. I believe that the work raises a number of questions and ideas for future work, and my program solves a number of the boring problems without getting into the interesting applications. However, I've previously been told that raising an idea in a "Future Work" section effectively 'reserves' that work for me, and it would be considered rude for readers to begin research on those areas.

How can I signal (without flat out saying that I don't care) that I hope others will pick up and run with the ideas I'm presenting?

If it's of any importance, it's a Computer Science paper.

Comment: Just don't write 'We are currently investigating...'

Comment: _«I've previously been told that raising an idea in a "Future Work" section effectively 'reserves' that work for me»_ -- Nobody ever told me this. I'm a horrible person :(

Comment: Isn't it precisely what the future work section is about?

Comment: I always thought of it as "*something that someone should do; I think*"

Comment: How about using a title like "Further Research Needed", which implies (to me, at least) that it's not you who is doing it, and someone else is "needed" to help...?

Comment: You can write: "It seems an interesting problem to..."

Comment: I am a mathematician, not a computer scientist, so please forgive a naive question: if you don't plan on doing future work related to the paper, why have a future work section at all?  Is it required?  (In mathematics ending papers in this way is actually somewhat discouraged.  It took me a few years to figure that out.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Mathematicians are discouraged from offering conjectures? Really?

Comment: @JeffE: I don't view a conjecture as being exactly the same as future work, but since you ask: in some circumstances, yes.  To say a little more: many journals (i) want writing to be very "formal" and (ii) view space as being at a premium.  When you combine these things, material that you put in a paper which is not fully supported and it is not closely related to the theorems and proofs you are contributing can be viewed as diluting the value of your paper.

Comment: Perhaps a more relevant remark: one of the specific criticisms I remember receiving about a "future work" section was that the work was described in a way that made the referee think that I was "staking out territory" much as the OP suggests.  This was objected to as being an improper use of the forum the journal was providing.  I didn't necessarily agree that that was what I was trying to do...but the easiest thing was simply to take that material out entirely.

Comment: What it actually means is "We procastrinated too much ourselves to do this and we're never going to do it anyway and we actually don't care."

Comment: As long as you phrase it as "These are things that someone could maybe do someday" rather than "The author is already looking into this stuff" then I don't see there being any confusion, really.

Comment: One of the first places to look when you are interested in extending a particular work is the "future works" section.  These are the authors' clues to what they felt would be promising ideas to consider, and is a valuable public service to the community if it is done thoughtfully.

Comment: In my field (an applied science) these sections are not uncommon. "These are things that someone could maybe do someday" is the general implication from "Future Work" sections. It's more of a "Here's the kind of questions that arose from my work. Anyone who wants to answer them, go for it" than "This is what I plan on doing next, this is my territory". In some cases the possible avenues of research opened up from a paper are so broad that the author may find it helpful to the scientific community to identify the areas he/she believes the first efforts of future research should be applied.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've never heard this about "Future Work".  Items that you put in this section are simply things that you are currently considering, and someone else who does them should at least cite your original work.  However, anyone who beats you to actually doing the work should be able to publish it.

If you want to make it absolutely clear that you do not intend to work on this material (and, you never know, you might end up going back to it later anyway!), simply call the section "Further discussion" or just "Discussion".

Comment: My favorite is "Open questions". Doesn't directly say that you're not following it up, but lacks the same implications that future work does.

Comment: +1. Not only haven't I heard of this kind of "reserving" the topic for oneself, I have seen it in use as a place where one can enumerate the holes in his theory in a manner which saves face: "I developed an algorithm which automatically designs the perfect user interface based on data gained from telepatically reading the stakeholders' thoughts. This paper focuses on the algorithm itself; developing a telepathy method for gathering the data in the field is future work."

Comment: Doesn't the section "Conclusion" contain the discussions?

Answer (score 24):

"While there is no further research planned by the author, there are several avenues that..."

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is just a matter of wording and rather than word it that *you* are going to do this "Future Work", maybe word it as *anyone* could do this future work. That way it shows you are thinking ahead (good thing) even though you may not want to do it.

To me, the Future Work would show that someone is thinking and would convince me that this work you have done is beneficial to the field and opens doors to other work.

Answer (score 3):

I have been told that you should not put your best, novel idea for future research in 'Future Work', you don't give away your state-of-the-art research ideas for free right? Experience teaches me that researchers often put stuff like 'investigate in new industry/product/setting' 'investigate longitudinal' 'go out of the lab and test with secondary data' 'add obvious moderator' 'control for variable Z that we did not account for' in this section.

Comment: For me, if I'm sure that I won't research in this topic anymore, I'll give it for free.